# Parsing JSON Data in Select Menu

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to do a simple search through JSON data and return a 'list' of object in a select jenu. The idea is to ask users for a zip code. Users will enter a zip code and click on a submit button. This fires a function that searches searches through JSON data for the zip code that the user entered in the search field. When a matching zip code is found the zip code and corresponding JSON data are returned as objects that can be used later in the application. Thanks to some help here the following code is working:

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KmYJw/17/

```
<div>
<input name="name" value="" type="text" />
<input value="search in json" type="submit" />
</div>
<a href="#">get location</a>


$(function() {
var city;
var json = {
"people": {
    "zipcode": [{
        "code": "12345",
        "city": "Chicago",
        "name": "Paul"},
    {
        "code": "12345",
        "city": "New York",
        "name": "Mary"}]
}
};

$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
    var searchName = $("input[name='code']").val();

    $.each(json.people.zipcode, function(i, v) {
        if (v.code == searchName) {
            city = v.city;
            return;
        }
    });
    return;
});

$('a').click(function(){
    alert(city);

});

});
```

Here is my problem. As you can see I have two zip codes that are the same and the above function returns only one city in an alert box.

I need for all related cities (many more will be added with the same zip code) to be displayed in a select menu. This way when more cities in the same zip code are found a user can easily choose which city they need to obtain data from.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
if (v.code == searchName) {
            city = v.city;
            return;
        }
```

do 
top declaration :

```
var cities = [];
```

on click event

```
if (v.code == searchName) {
            cities.push(v.city);

        }

$('a').click(function(){
    alert(cities.join(''));

});
```

here you go: 
code for populating elements :
http://jsfiddle.net/vGSXD/

```
var cities = ["M1", "M2", "M3"],
    citiesNode = document.getElementById('cities'),
    option = '';

for (var i = 0, l = cities.length; i < l ; i+=1)
{
    option = document.createElement('OPTION');
    option.text = cities[i];
    citiesNode.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. How would I get the results to populate a html select menu instead of in the alert?

Comment: some handcrafting required. give few mins may be. you'd like just simple select? Am I correct?

Comment: Your code is listing the objects from the array in the select. I need the objects matching the Zip to be pulled from the JSON data and populate the select menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understand what are you trying to achieve, but it looks like the only thing you need is to manage the zipcode/cities relation into an array instead of breaking the search on the first finding.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
    var searchName = $("input[name='code']").val();
var zipNCities=new Array();

    $.each(json.people.zipcode, function(i, v) {
        if (v.code == searchName) {
           //use zipcode in the array for future search by city, where you will have  
           //multiple zipcodes
            zipNCities.push({zipcode: v.code, city: v.city});
        }
    });
    return;
});

$('a').click(function(){
   //display cities from the array here.

});
```

Comment: Just to clarify the user workflow: a zip code is entered and the submit button pressed; the JSON file is parsed to find the zip code; then all cities in the zip code need to populate a html select menu (dropdown). Currently only one city is being displayed in an alert.

Comment: then, the other answer fits better ;).